# How label properly original observations with predicted clusters using kmeans in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, cluster-analysis, apache-spark-mllib

I'd like to understand how the k-means method works in PySpark.
For this, I've done this small example:

```
In [120]: entry = [ [1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[1,1,1],[5,5,5]]

In [121]: rdd_entry = sc.parallelize(entry)

In [122]: clusters = KMeans.train(rdd_entry, k=5, maxIterations=10, initializationMode="random")

In [123]:  rdd_labels = clusters.predict(rdd_entry)

In [125]: rdd_labels.collect()
Out[125]: [3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2]

In [126]: entry
Out[126]:
[[1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4],
 [5, 5, 5],
 [5, 5, 5],
 [5, 5, 5],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [5, 5, 5]]
```

At first glance it seems that rdd_labels returns the cluster to which each observation belongs, respecting the order of the original rdd. Although in this example it is evident, **how can I be sure in a case where I will work with 8 million observations?**

Also, I'd like to know how to join rdd_entry and rdd_labels, respecting that order, so that each observation of rdd_entry is correctly labeled with its cluster.
I tried to do a .join(), but it jumps error

```
In [127]: rdd_total = rdd_entry.join(rdd_labels)

In [128]: rdd_total.collect()

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: are you confined to use `pyspark.mllib` (soon to be deprecated), or you'd possibly like a solution based on `pyspark.ml` (i.e. the preferred, dataframe-based API)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it helps! (this solution is based on `pyspark.ml`)

```py
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

#sample data
df = sc.parallelize([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[1,1,1],[5,5,5]]).\
    toDF(('col1','col2','col3'))

vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=df.columns, outputCol="features")
vector_df = vecAssembler.transform(df)

#kmeans clustering
kmeans=KMeans(k=3, seed=1)
model=kmeans.fit(vector_df)
predictions=model.transform(vector_df)
predictions.show()
```

Output is:

```
+----+----+----+-------------+----------+
|col1|col2|col3|     features|prediction|
+----+----+----+-------------+----------+
|   1|   1|   1|[1.0,1.0,1.0]|         0|
|   2|   2|   2|[2.0,2.0,2.0]|         0|
|   3|   3|   3|[3.0,3.0,3.0]|         2|
|   4|   4|   4|[4.0,4.0,4.0]|         1|
|   5|   5|   5|[5.0,5.0,5.0]|         1|
|   5|   5|   5|[5.0,5.0,5.0]|         1|
|   5|   5|   5|[5.0,5.0,5.0]|         1|
|   1|   1|   1|[1.0,1.0,1.0]|         0|
|   5|   5|   5|[5.0,5.0,5.0]|         1|
+----+----+----+-------------+----------+
```

---

Although `pyspark.ml` has better approach I thought of writing code to achieve the same result using `pyspark.mllib` (trigger was the comment from @Muhammad). So here goes the solution based on `pyspark.mllib`...

```py
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

#sample data
rdd = sc.parallelize([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[1,1,1],[5,5,5]])

#K-Means example
model = KMeans.train(rdd, k=3, seed=1)
labels = model.predict(rdd)

#add cluster label to the original data
df1 = rdd.toDF(('col1','col2','col3')) \
         .withColumn('row_index', row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(labels, IntegerType()).toDF(('label')) \
           .withColumn('row_index', row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())))
df = df1.join(df2, on=["row_index"]).drop("row_index")
df.show()
```

Comment: sorry, I couldn't prove it until now. I just did it and it works. Thank you :)

Comment: @Prem Is there any solution in pyspark.mllib.clustering

Comment: @Muhammad I have added code to have the same result using `pyspark.mllib`. Hope it helps!